# Matching two words with some characters in between in regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I want to do a match for a string when no `abc` is followed by some characters (possibly none) and ends with `.com`.

I tried with the following:

```
(?!abc).*\.com
```

or

```
(?!abc).*?\.com
```

or

```
(?<!abc).*\.com
```

or

```
(?<!abc).*?\.com
```

But none of these worked. Please help.

Many thanks!

**Edit**

Sorry if I did not make myself clear. Just give some examples. I want `def.edu`, `abc.com`, `abce.com`,　`eabc.com` and `abcAnYTHing.com` do not match, while `a.com`, `b.com`, `ab.com`, `ae.com` etc. match.

Comment: Qiang - sorry, your edit doesn't clarify enough. As I noted in my asnwer, the REALLY important questions is whether it should match "def.edu"

Comment: In which language are you programming? There may be a better way to tackle this problem.

Comment: @Johnsyweb:　I wanted to know the solution to this question in `perl`, `python`, `java`..., but not in `.NET`. :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I added Perl tag so Perl-dwelling RegEx experts can have a look-see in case I missed anything

Comment: @DVK: Why not 'Python' and 'Java'?

Comment: @Johnsy - because I'm familiar with Perl tag ecosystem and know that lots of RegEx experts hang out there. Not familiar with either of your 2 proposed tags, but SERIOUSLY doubt there are more RegEx experts on Java area vs. Perl :)

Comment: @DVK: That's a fair point, but will a PCRE work in whichever language Qiang decides to implement the solution? Anyway, I'm not sure squeezing all of this logic is the best idea, as per [my answer, below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617358/matching-two-words-with-some-characters-in-between-in-regular-expression/7617942#7617942).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear from your wording if you want to match a string ending with `.com` AND NOT containing `abc` before that; or to match a string that doesn't have "abc followed by characters followed by .com".

Meaning, in the first case, `"def.edu"` does NOT match (no "abc" but doesn't end with ".com") but in the second case `"def.edu"` matches (because it's not "abcSOMETHING.com")

---

In the first case, you need to use **negative look-behind**:

```
(?<!abc.+)\.com$
# Use .* instead of .+ if you want "abc.com" to fail as well
```

**IMPORTANT**: your original expression using look-behind - #3 ( `(?<!abc).*\.com` ) - **didn't work** because look-behind ONLY looks behind **immediately** preceding the next term. Therefore, the "something after abc" should be included in the look-behind together with `abc` - as my RegEx above does.

**PROBLEM**: my RegEx above likely **won't work** with your specific RegEx Engine, unless it **supports general look-behinds with variable length expression** (like the one above) - which ONLY `.NET` does these days (A good summary of what does and doesn't support what flavors of look-behind is at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html ).

If that is indeed the case, you will have to do double match: first, check for `.com`; capturing everything before it; then negative match on abc. I will use Perl syntax since you didn't specify a language:

```
if (/^(.*)\.com$/) {
    if ($1 !~ /abc/) { 
    # Or, you can just use a substring:
    # if (index($1, "abc") < 0) {
        # PROFIT!
    }
}
```

---

In the second case, the EASIEST thing to do is to do a "does not match" operator - e.g. `!~` in Perl (or negate a result of a match if your language doesn't support "does not match"). Example using pseudo-code:

```
if (NOT string.match(/abc.+\.com$/)) ...
```

Please note that you don't need ".+"/".*" when using negative lookbehind;

Comment: `(?<!abc).+\.com$` matches `abce.com` actually, and not `ae.com`, which is exactly opposite to what I wanted.

Comment: Yes, the second code snippet works. Is there a single regex to do this? thanks a lot.

Comment: @Quiang Li - figured it out. My lookbehind had a bug (`.+` needed to be inside capture braces). The problem is that, of course, variable length lookbehind like the one I produced isn't supported outside `.NET` RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

***Condensing:***

`Sorry if I did not make myself clear. Just give some examples.`
`I want def.edu, abc.com, abce.com, eabc.com and`
`abcAnYTHing.com do not match,`
`while a.com, b.com, ab.com, ae.com etc. match.`

New regex after revised OP examples:
`/^(?:(?!abc.*\.com\$|^def\.edu\$).)+\.(?:com|edu)\$/s`

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my @samples = qw/
 <newline>
   shouldn't_pass 
   def.edu  abc.com  abce.com eabc.com 
 <newline>
   should_pass.com
   a.com    b.com    ab.com   ae.com
   abc.edu  def.com  defa.edu
 /;

my $regex = qr
  /
    ^    # Begin string
      (?:  # Group    

          (?!              # Lookahead ASSERTION
                abc.*\.com$     # At any character position, cannot have these in front of us.
              | ^def\.edu$      # (or 'def.*\.edu$')
           )               # End ASSERTION

           .               # This character passes

      )+   # End group, do 1 or more times

      \.   # End of string check,
      (?:com|edu)   # must be a '.com' or '.edu' (remove if not needed)

    $    # End string
  /sx;


print "\nmatch using   /^(?:(?!abc.*\.com\$|^def\.edu\$).)+\.(?:com|edu)\$/s \n";

for  my $str ( @samples )
{
   if ( $str =~ /<newline>/ ) {
      print "\n"; next;
   }

   if ( $str =~ /$regex/ ) {
       printf ("passed - $str\n");
   }
   else {
       printf ("failed - $str\n");
   }
}
```

Output:

match using   `/^(?:(?!abc.*.com$|^def.edu$).)+.(?:com|edu)$/`s

failed - shouldn't_pass
failed - def.edu
failed - abc.com
failed - abce.com
failed - eabc.com

passed - should_pass.com
passed - a.com
passed - b.com
passed - ab.com
passed - ae.com
passed - abc.edu
passed - def.com
passed - defa.edu

Comment: Can you please explain a bit your regexp given here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Condensed previous regex to new one based on revised OP examples.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56366/147331).

[DVK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617358/matching-two-words-with-some-characters-in-between-in-regular-expression/7617394#7617394) shows you how you *can* tackle this problem using regular expressions, like you asked for.

My solution (in Python) demonstrates that regular expressions are not necessarily the best approach and that tackling the problem using your programming language's string-handling functionality may produce a more efficient and more maintainable solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest

def is_valid_domain(domain):
    return domain.endswith('.com') and 'abc' not in domain

class TestIsValidDomain(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_edu_invalid(self):
        self.assertFalse(is_valid_domain('def.edu'))

    def test_abc_invalid(self):
        self.assertFalse(is_valid_domain('abc.com'))
        self.assertFalse(is_valid_domain('abce.com'))
        self.assertFalse(is_valid_domain('abcAnYTHing.com'))

    def test_dotcom_valid(self):
        self.assertTrue(is_valid_domain('a.com'))
        self.assertTrue(is_valid_domain('b.com'))
        self.assertTrue(is_valid_domain('ab.com'))
        self.assertTrue(is_valid_domain('ae.com'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

[See it run](https://ideone.com/BePKb)!

**Update**

Even in a language like Perl, where regular expressions are idiomatic, there's no reason to squash all of your logic into a single regex. A function like this would be far easier to maintain:

```
sub is_domain_valid {
    my $domain = shift;
    return $domain =~ /\.com$/ && $domain !~ /abc/;
}
```

(I'm not a Perl programmer, [but this runs and gives the results that you desire](https://ideone.com/IOkdY))

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to exclude strings that *start* with `abc`?  That is, would `xyzabc.com` be okay?  If so, this regex should work:

```
^(?!abc).+\.com$
```

If you want to make sure `abc` doesn't appear *anywhere*, use this:

```
^(?:(?!abc).)+\.com$
```

In the first regex, the lookahead is applied only once, at the beginning of the string.  In the second regex the lookahead is applied each time the `.` is about to match a character, ensuring that the character is not the beginning of an `abc` sequence.

Comment: I want `xyzabc.com` not to match.