# What is the reason for perfomance difference for substring search using "index()" vs RegEx in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, search

I am assuming there might be an efficiency difference between:

```
if (index($string, "abc") < -1) {}
```

and

```
if ($string !~ /abc/) {}
```

Could someone confirm that this is the case based on how both are implemented in Perl (as opposed to pure benchmarking)?

I can obviously make a guess as to how both are implemented (based on how I would write both in C) but would like more informed answer ideally based on actual `perl` sourcecode.

---

Here's my own sample benchmark:

```
                          Rate regex.FIND_AT_END    index.FIND_AT_END
regex.FIND_AT_END     639345/s                   --                 -88%
index.FIND_AT_END    5291005/s                 728%                   --
                          Rate regex.NOFIND         index.NOFIND
regex.NOFIND          685260/s                   --                 -88%
index.NOFIND         5515720/s                 705%                   --
                          Rate regex.FIND_AT_START  index.FIND_AT_START
regex.FIND_AT_START   672269/s                   --                 -90%
index.FIND_AT_START  7032349/s                 946%                   --
```

```
##############################
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $count = 10000000;
my $re = qr/abc/o;
my %tests = (
    "NOFIND        " => "cvxcvidgds.sdfpkisd[s"
   ,"FIND_AT_END   " => "cvxcvidgds.sdfpabcd[s"
   ,"FIND_AT_START " => "abccvidgds.sdfpkisd[s"
);

foreach my $type (keys %tests) {
    my $str = $tests{$type};
    cmpthese($count, {
        "index.$type" => sub { my $idx = index($str, "abc"); },
        "regex.$type" => sub { my $idx = ($str =~ $re); }
    });
}
```

Comment: BTW, if my benchmark is not the best approach to test these, please  propose a more appropriate one.

Comment: This is more of a theoretical question which popped into my head while answering this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617358/matching-two-words-with-some-characters-in-between-in-regular-expression/7617394#7617394

Comment: Could you add a third test: `"rege2.$type" => sub { my $idx = ($str =~ /abc/o); }` Interestingly (or not?), it does not give the same results as the regex test on my machine (perl 5.12.3) - much closer to the `index` cases.

Comment: Did you try it with longer strings? On Mac OS Lion and homebrew `perl 5.14.1`, using 16K strings, I do not find much of a difference between `FIND_AT_END` and `NOFIND`. `FIND_AT_START` is still much faster.

Comment: Plus, IIRC, the `/o` switch was only relevant on older `perl`s and even then only if there was variable interpolation.

Comment: @Sinan - the thrust of the question is more of differences between index/regex in each case vs. comparative differences between 3 test cases.

Comment: @Mat - good point (I saw this in the original benchmark version but forgot). Re-adding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the function [`Perl_instr`](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/cc92ef02098c000d945bcf93c92bdb2a0a05fa97:/util.c#l431):

```c
 430 char *
 431 Perl_instr(register const char *big, register const char *little)
 432 {
 433     register I32 first;
 434 
 435     PERL_ARGS_ASSERT_INSTR;
 436 
 437     if (!little)
 438         return (char*)big;
 439     first = *little++;
 440     if (!first)
 441         return (char*)big;
 442     while (*big) {
 443         register const char *s, *x;
 444         if (*big++ != first)
 445             continue;
 446         for (x=big,s=little; *s; /**/ ) {
 447             if (!*x)
 448                 return NULL;
 449             if (*s != *x)
 450                 break;
 451             else {
 452                 s++;
 453                 x++;
 454             }
 455         }
 456         if (!*s)
 457             return (char*)(big-1);
 458     }
 459     return NULL;
 460 }
```

Compare with [S_regmatch](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/cc92ef02098c000d945bcf93c92bdb2a0a05fa97:/regexec.c#l2991). It seems to me that there is some overhead in `regmatch` compared to `index` ;-)

Comment: You forgot to put "<british accent>" around your understatement :)

Comment: @DVK Of course, for a real answer, one would have to actually know something about what happens with `/abc/` and I don't presume to begin to understand it. But, yeah, it would be great if I could do a proper British accent.